# TimeSeries conversion from CET / CEST to UTC

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pytz, datetimeoffset

I have two time series file which is meant to be in CET / CEST. The bad one of them, does not write the values in a proper way. For the good csv, see here:

```
#test_good.csv
local_time,value
...
2017-03-26 00:00,2016
2017-03-26 01:00,2017
2017-03-26 03:00,2018
2017-03-26 04:00,2019
...
2017-10-29 01:00,7224
2017-10-29 02:00,7225
2017-10-29 02:00,7226
2017-10-29 03:00,7227
...
```

...everything works fine by using:

```
        df['utc_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[local_time_column])
                            .dt.tz_localize('CET', ambiguous="infer")
                            .dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

When converting the test_bad.csv to UTC I get an AmbiguousTimeError as the 2 hours in October are missing.

```
# test_bad.csv
local_time,value
...
2017-03-26 00:00,2016
2017-03-26 01:00,2017   # everything is as it should be
2017-03-26 03:00,2018
2017-03-26 04:00,2019
...
2017-10-29 01:00,7223
2017-10-29 02:00,7224   # the value of 2 am should actually be repeated PLUS 3 am is missing
2017-10-29 04:00,7226
2017-10-29 05:00,7227
...
```

Does anyone know an elegant way of how to still convert the time series file to UTC and add NaN columns for the missing dates in the new index? Thanks for your help.

Comment: to understand correctly, your second example (the "bad" data) has missing entries and you want fill them with NaN? Also, is the frequency constant (hourly)?

Comment: @MrFuppes, yes I am dealing with hourly data. At best, I would like to fill the missing entries with the respective CEST / CET datetime values so that the conversion succeeds like in the first example.

Comment: Unfortunately if you did not record whether the time was before or after the transition, there's no way to reliably resolve the ambiguity.  Is #7225 missing from the CSV file or did Pandas drop it?

Comment: side note, if you format to string coming from UTC datetime, pass on that information by using a format like `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ'` with the Z denoting UTC.

Comment: @MarkRansom, borth values 2017-10-29 02:00 (2nd apperance) and 2017-10-29 03:00 are missing in the initial file. They were not dropped. I also thought about just creating a new CET index and then reindex however then I am getting the error that reindexing is not possible due to duplicate values from DST in October

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating a bit on Mark Ransom's comment;

```
2017-10-29 02:00,7224
```

is ambiguous; it could be `2017-10-29 00:00 UTC` ***or*** `2017-10-29 01:00 UTC`. That's why pd.to_datetime refuses to infer anything.

With the help of some native Python, you can work around. Assuming you just loaded the csv to a df without parsing anything to datetime, you can continue like

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

df['local_time'] = [pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(datetime.fromisoformat(t)) for t in df['local_time']]

# so you can make a UTC index:
df.set_index(df['local_time'].dt.tz_convert('UTC'), inplace=True)

# Now you can create a new, hourly index from that and re-index:
dti = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='H')
df2 = df.reindex(dti)

# for comparison, the "re-created" local_time column:
df2['local_time'] = df2.index.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').values
```

that should give you something like

```
df2
                            value           local_time
2017-03-25 23:00:00+00:00  2016.0  2017-03-26 00:00:00
2017-03-26 00:00:00+00:00  2017.0  2017-03-26 01:00:00
2017-03-26 01:00:00+00:00  2018.0  2017-03-26 03:00:00
2017-03-26 02:00:00+00:00  2019.0  2017-03-26 04:00:00
2017-03-26 03:00:00+00:00     NaN  2017-03-26 05:00:00
                          ...                  ...
2017-10-29 00:00:00+00:00     NaN  2017-10-29 02:00:00
2017-10-29 01:00:00+00:00  7224.0  2017-10-29 02:00:00 # note: value randomly attributed to "second" 2 am
2017-10-29 02:00:00+00:00     NaN  2017-10-29 03:00:00
2017-10-29 03:00:00+00:00  7226.0  2017-10-29 04:00:00
2017-10-29 04:00:00+00:00  7227.0  2017-10-29 05:00:00
```

As commented above, the value `7224` is attributed to `2017-10-29 01:00:00 UTC`, but it could as well be attributed to `2017-10-29 00:00:00 UTC` If you don't care, you're fine. If that's a problem, best you can do in my opinion is discard the value. You can do so by using

```
df['local_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['local_time']).dt.tz_localize('Europe/Berlin', ambiguous='NaT')
```

instead of the native Python part in the code above.

Comment: @MrFupppes, thanks a lot. I see. I think it would be great if one could attribute it to  2017-10-29 00:00:00 UTC but I have not found a way to get there yet.

Comment: @GregorJohnen you can enforce this by setting `is_dst=True` when calling the localize method ([docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#tzinfo-api)). If you set this keyword, pytz will localize to the time where DST was active in case of an ambiguous date/time (as in your case). Problem I see is: this might work in this specific case but might not be *always*  the desired behavior...

Comment: @Mr Fuppes, what do you think of working with timedeltas instead and then reindex based on a complete CET vector which will avoid running into trouble because of a duplicate axis in the latter? This would insert NaNs for the missing columns in the value vector. Afterwords one could convert the timedeltas again to datetime (CET) and then localize the local time column as UTC. What do you think?

Comment: @MachineYogi at the moment, I'm not sure how this would be different from a (strictly monotonically increasing) UTC datetime column. But if you think this is a viable approach and gives you the desired result, why not add it as an answer?

Comment: @MachineYogi you would also create the localized datetime column with a list comprehension, but without parsing from string - e.g. `df['local_time'] = [pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(t) for t in df['local_time']]`

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide the solution which I am using for this workaround:
It uses some try: except: functionality in case of the ambiguous time error. This should on the one hand side convert the time vector to UTC while it also fills missing values by reindexin. Feel free to suggest improvements.

```
try: # here everything is as expected and one hour is missing in Mar and one hour is repeated in Oct

# Localize tz-naive index of the DataFrame to target time zone.
df['time'] = df.iloc[:,0].dt.tz_localize('CET', ambiguous='infer').dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['time'], utc=True))

# Create a complete time vector in UTC for latter reindexing
idx = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq=freq, tz='UTC')

# Verify that time vector is complete
if len(np.unique(np.diff(df.index))) == 1:
    print('Time vector is complete!')
else:
    # print dates which are not in the sequence and add them while simultaneously adding NaNs to the data columns
    print(f'These dates are not in the sequence:{idx.difference(df["utc_time"])}')
    df = df.reindex(idx).rename_axis('time')
    
except pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: # here python does not know how to handle the non-reapeated time

# create the localized datetime column with a list comprehension
df['time'] = [pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin').localize(t, is_dst=True) for t in df.iloc[:, 0]]

# make an UTC index:
df.set_index(df['time'].dt.tz_convert('UTC'), inplace=True)

# create a new index of desired frequency from that and re-index:
idx = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq=freq, tz='UTC')


# Verify that time vector is complete
if len(np.unique(np.diff(df.index))) == 1:
    print('Time vector is complete!')
else:
    # print dates which are not in the sequence and add them while simultaneously adding NaNs to the data columns
    print(f'These were the dates which were not in the sequence:{pd.Series(idx.difference(df["time"]))}')
    df = df.reindex(idx).rename_axis('time')
```